# Is $x\in\{\{x\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $x\in\{\{x\}\}$. I understand that $x\in\{x\}\in\{\{x\}\}$ does this mean $x\in\{\{x\}\}$?

Very simple just unsure about the properties of $\in$, not looking for an extravagant answer, thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. $\{\{x\}\}$ has exactly one element, namely $\{x\}$.

In general, to test if $a\in b$, we do the following:

1. Is $b$ a set?
2. If so, is $a$ one of the elements in the set $b$?

$a$ can be a set itself, or not, doesn't matter.

Comment: And $x\neq \{x\}$, by the axiom of regularity.

Comment: Even without AR, so long as $x\neq \{x\}$ for ANY $x$, the conclusion fails to hold.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Good analogy is *list* in programming language Python.